# plotting histograms next to each other

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have 4 histograms form 4 different df. I can plot them one by one but can't figure a way to plot them all next to each other, let's stay 2 on top, 2 at the bottom.

```
hist_1 = df1.hist(bins=50,range=[0,1])
hist_2 = df2.hist(bins=50,range=[0,1])
hist_3 = df3.hist(bins=50,range=[0,1])
hist_4 = df4.hist(bins=50,range=[0,1])
```

I have tried different things but it is always showing them overlapped on the same figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you are expecting? Using `subplots` divide the axes into 4 (2 at the top and 2 at the bottom) and then plot the histograms for each df in each subplot.

Code:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True)
axs = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

for n in range(len(axs)):
    axs[n].hist(dfs[n], bins=50, range=[0,1])
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much davidbilla this is exactly what I was expecting!!